# What is a valid binding name for azure function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

When I try to run the azure function defined below, I get the following error log

```
The 'my_function' function is in error: The binding name my_function_timer is invalid. Please assign a valid name to the binding.
```

**What is the format of a valid binding name for Azure Function ?**

### Function definition

I have two files in `my_function` directory:

- `__init__.py` contains the python code of the function
- `function.json` contains the configuration of the function

Here is the content of those two files

#### `__init__.py`

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

def main(my_function_timer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    logging.info("My function starts")
    print("hello world")
    logging.info("My function stops")
```

#### `function.json`

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "my_function_timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 1 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

I deploy this function using [Azure/functions-action@v1](https://github.com/Azur/functions-action) github action

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation either, but looking at the source code of [azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host)(which [contains code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host#azure-functions-host) for the runtime host used by the Azure Functions service), it uses following [regex](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/de24ce6714a2092f05f2f63ff34f64beba880ce4/src/WebJobs.Script/Utility.cs#L48) to [validate](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/de24ce6714a2092f05f2f63ff34f64beba880ce4/src/WebJobs.Script/Utility.cs#L576-L587) the binding `name`.

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,127}|\$return)$
```

This means that a valid binding name must be either:

- *Alpha numeric characters(with atmost 127 characters)*

  *OR*
- *Literal string `$return`*

Since your binding name contains an underscore(`_`), the above regex does not match which will result in [validation error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/de24ce6714a2092f05f2f63ff34f64beba880ce4/src/WebJobs.Script/Utility.cs#L580).

Comment: A bit annoying for python users regarding pep8 compliance..

Comment: And why oh why does it not give an error on deploy!

Comment: Seems like it is a bug to report